# Referred as ... below

Tags: rules

When I'm writing a rule, I meet a problem that I need to define a word used below. For example:

> 1. "Group", or "The Group" below means "the ??? Group."
> 2. The Group will not......

How can I rewrite point 1 to make it correct?

## Edit

After reading the comments, there are these solutions:

> 1. The Game Group, hereinafter referred as the Group...
> 2. The Group, as described above...
> 3. The Game Group ("Group")

Comment: By the way, anybody explain the downvote? *Not a constructive question*?

Comment: I think there are many ways to do this, depending on the formality and nature of the writing. In a legal document, you might see *"The Scrooge Group, hereinafter referred to as the Group"*. In an informal document, you might see *"The Scrooge Group, which I'll be calling the Evil Empire from now on"*. And in a scientific paper, it might just be *"ribonucleic acid (RNA)",* where RNA is used after the first mention.

Comment: But either way, it's common to give something a shortened name at its first actual mention, and not before (as you seem to be planning to do).

Comment: 1': The Game Group (henceforth "the Group")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you searching for something like this ?

> The *"group"*, as described below, cannot do this and that
>
> [...]
>
> The *"group"* is composed of Bob, Albert and every child with blue eyes and ...

If not, try to improve your answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Something like this... but can I say something like *The group is the Microsoft group used below* in a more formal... or correct way?

Comment: @Jamie Like *"The Microsoft group refered below as the group"* ?

Comment: @Jamie I generally see the following in writing: _The Microsoft Group ("Group")..._. The quotes are optional, of course. The point is to name the group, then immediately identify its nickname in the document.